# How could I validate a file for my program? C++

Tags: c++, file, function

I have a program that reads a file and then do various things with the information that it reads.

Now, I want to make a function that checks all the information that is inside the file before allocating the information into memory.

I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is correct but that's my idea and I don't know how to do it.
If you have better ideas for doing this, feel free to tell me.

Here is the function I want to implement and the function that reads the file.

```
void Arreglo::FileValidation(ifstream &entrada)
{
    //implementation of the function
}

void Arreglo::Registro(ifstream &entrada)
{
  entrada >> Cantidad;
  Dealer = new Element[Cantidad];

  for (int i = 0; i < Cantidad; i++) {
      entrada >> Dealer[i].CompanyName;

      entrada >> Dealer[i].AmountModels;
      if (Dealer[i].AmountModels > MaxModel)
          MaxModel = Dealer[i].AmountModels;

      Dealer[i].Modelo = new Detail[Dealer[i].AmountModels];

    for (int j = 0; j < Dealer[i].AmountModels; j++) {
        entrada >> Dealer[i].Modelo[j].ModelName
            >> Dealer[i].Modelo[j].Sales;
    }
  }
}
```

More information:

I want to check that the information inside the file is like this.

```
4
Toyota
6
Corolla 1
Tercel 1
Avalon 1
Camry 1
Yaris 1
Supra 1
Mazda
6
3 8
5 2
6 2
2 2
Legend 2
RX7 2
Nissan
6
Sentra 3
Altima 3
Optima 3
350Z 3
Cube 3
GT-R 3
Acura
4
RSX 4
Legend 4
RDX 5
TL 6
```

PD: Sorry for my English.

Comment: Any chance that you could use XML as the serialization strategy for this data?  Then it would be easier to validate the schema for your data.

Answer (score 1):

The reading and validating must be done hand in hand, you can't validate and then read (at least not easily).

What exactly to validate will strongly depend on how mangled the input data could be. It might be as simple as doing almost nothing, just reading in the data; consider mild conditions (check for overlong strings, numbers must be in certain ranges); all the range up to extremely paranoid, as checking that numbers are written as numbers and don't contain letters or other cruft, that names, say, are in a list of approved names.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to check? Whether the file is changed by some one or it is in the correct format?
If you want to track if it is changed, just append the checksum of the data content at the end (or begining) of the file. When you read the file back, you can compare the checksum of the data content against the checksum saved at the end (or begining).

Comment: Yes, I want to check that the file is in the correct format. If its correct, cout << "File Validated" if its not "Error, the input file could not be read, check format". Something like that.

Comment: Checksum cannot be used to validate the format. As Tony_D stated you have to validate it as you read it.

Answer (score 1):

You should learn to validate data as you read it:

```
void Arreglo::Registro(ifstream &entrada)
{
  if (!(entrada >> Cantidad))
      throw std::runtime_error("input missing dealer count");

  Dealer = new Element[Cantidad];

  for (int i = 0; i < Cantidad; i++) {
      if (!(entrada >> Dealer[i].CompanyName))
          throw std::runtime_error("input missing company name");

      ...etc...
```